# Add print in Scotty do block

Tags: haskell, scotty

I'm very new to Haskell so sorry in advance if the question is silly, but I was not able to find the solution in google.

Let's say that I have this program using the [Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) web framework:

```
responseUserByName :: ActionM ()
responseUserByName = do name <- param "name"
                        user <- liftAndCatchIO $ getUserByUserName name
                        json user
```

I would like to add a log since it is failing at runtime and I cannot tell why. So my idea was to add some print in the do block to check values.

But since the `do` block has to return a `ActionM` I cannot print and return an `IO`. Well or at least I don't know how.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `ActionM` is from [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.2/docs/Web-Scotty.html#t:ActionM). In that case, you can simply lift IO actions with `liftIO`, like you already do with `liftAndCatchIO`:

```
responseUserByName :: ActionM ()
responseUserByName =
    do name <- param "name"
       user <- liftAndCatchIO $ getUserByUserName name
       liftIO $ putStrLn "this is a log message"
       json user
```