# How to use System.cmd in Scotty action

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to learn how do statements in haskell work. I a trying to make a very simple program where you can call a REST endpoint and execute a system command (something very simple like "ls") The problem comes with combining different actions types in a single do statement.

```
import Web.Scotty
import System.Cmd

main = do
  putStrLn "Starting Server"
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/url" $ do                         
      system "ls"
      text "Success"
```

But I get the next compiler error:

```
Main.hs:12:7:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                                    Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO a0’
                with actual type ‘IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: system "ls"
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘do { system "ls";
            text "Success" }’
```

I am having a hard time trying to learn Haskell!

Comment: I don't have time for a full explanation/answer - which involves features of the Haskell type system that you may not have encountered yet - but this should work if you replace `system "ls"` with `liftIO $ system "ls"`. (`liftIO` is from the `Control.Monad.IO.Class` module). I can attempt an explanation when I have more time later, if someone else hasn't done so yet.

Comment: You seem to know what the problem is - now use [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.5/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#v:liftIO) to fix it :-) Compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865577/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, [`do`-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) is used to chain statement-like things. A statement is some type constructor like `IO` applied to a particular result type. For example, the statement `system "ls"` has type `IO ExitCode`.

Other type constructors other than `IO` can work as statements. All that `do`-notation requires is that the type constructor implements the [`Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) which explains how to chain statements sensibly.

However, within a single `do`-block, *only one* type of statement is allowed! They must be all `IO` statements, or all `ActionT Text IO` statements. In your example you are mixing the two, which causes the error. Scotty's [`get`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) function expects an [`ActionT Text IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.5/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT) statement:

```
get :: RoutePattern -> ActionM () -> ScottyM ()
-- ActionM is actually a synonym for ActionT Text IO
```

The good news is that there's a way to convert (the usual Haskell term is "lift") `IO` statements into `ActionT Text IO` statements. The latter are actually a kind of "decorator"   (the usual Haskell term is ["monad transformer"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_Transformers_Explained)) over `IO` actions, which enable extra functionality related to Scotty. You can "lift" `IO` actions into the decorator using the [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO) function, like this:

```
get "/url" $ do                         
     liftIO (system "ls")
     text "Success"
```

In general, when can we use `liftIO` to lift a plain `IO` statement into a "decorated" statement? The "decorator" type constructor must have a [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO) instance besides the usual `Monad` instance. `MonadIO` is what provides the `liftIO` function.

In our case, looking at the available instances for [`ActionT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.5/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT):

```
(MonadIO m, ScottyError e) => MonadIO (ActionT e m)
```

Which means something like "if `m` is has a `MonadIO` instance—like `IO` trivially does—and the error type `e` has a `ScottyError` instance—like `Text` does—then we can lift `IO` statements to `ActionT e m` statements".

And the specialized type for `liftIO` is:

```
liftIO :: IO a -> ActionT Text IO a
```

Comment: I'd prefer to call these "values" or "expressions", not "statements" - even if they are statement-like in `do` notation.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, in Haskell all "statements" are actually values like any other. In a way, the `Monad` typeclass defines what operations and laws a type must satisfy in order for its values to be statement-like.

Comment: @Bergi Curiously, the Haskell report uses `do { stmts }` in the reference [grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14), and `;` is called an "empty statement", so I guess the official term is statement. This is probably not the best term, for the reasons you mention.

Comment: I think the idea is that monadic values in Haskell correspond to statements in imperative languages. This is clear in the case of `IO`, which is presumably what motivated the idea, but more of a stretch with other monads. For example a `State s a` value can feel quite "statement-like" (particularly those which alter the state and ignore the result value), but it would feel very awkward to describe, say, a list as a "statement".

Comment: @ch You have to admit, there are a *lot* of things in Haskell that could do with better names :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond This is very subjective but, do-blocks in the list monad do feel like composed of statements to me! Yes, there's a difference with `IO` in that each identifier bound with a `<-` corresponds not to a single value, but to a whole level in an implicit search tree. List "statements" have the "effect" of adding new levels to the tree. I still see this as sequential, if only logically, and have trouble visualizing the search tree when not using do notation.